# Parsing static routes from Cisco ios-xr Router with ttp parser and python

Tags: python, parsing, cisco

to check many static routes from cisco ios-xr router, i want to you use the "ttp parser" for parsing the output into a structurate data.
I have this output from the show command "show running-config router static".
We see that we have global and vrf entries, and static routes with and without description.

---

show output from router

---

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ios-xr#show running-config router static                      
router static
 maximum path ipv4 10000
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  10.2.1.128/26 172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall
  10.2.4.0/24 172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall
 vrf admeg
  address-family ipv4 unicastaaaaaa
   10.1.192.0/24 172.28.49.140 description customerA
   10.1.194.128/26 172.28.49.140 description customerB
   10.1.195.0/25 172.28.49.140 description something
 vrf aegeg
  address-family ipv4 unicastbbbbbb
   10.0.0.0/8 10.49.17.134
   10.175.154.236/32 10.49.17.134
```

---

This is my ttp parer

---

```
router static
 maximum path ipv4 10000
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  <group name="global.routes">
  {{ prefix }} {{ destination | ORPHRASE  }}
  </group>  
 <group name="{{ vrf_name }}">  
 vrf {{ vrf_name }}
  address-family ipv4 unicast
   <group name="routes">
   {{ prefix }} {{ destination | ORPHRASE }}
   </group> 
 </group>
```

---

And this is the output:

---

```
[
    {
        "admeg": {
            "routes": [
                {
                    "destination": "172.28.49.140 description customerA",
                    "prefix": "10.1.192.0/24"
                },
                {
                    "destination": "172.28.49.140 description customerB",
                    "prefix": "10.1.194.128/26"
                },
                {
                    "destination": "172.28.49.140 description something",
                    "prefix": "10.1.195.0/25"
                }
            ]
        },
        "aegeg": {
            "routes": [
                {
                    "destination": "10.49.17.134",
                    "prefix": "10.0.0.0/8"
                },
                {
                    "destination": "10.49.17.134",
                    "prefix": "10.175.154.236/32"
                }
            ]
        },
        "global": {
            "routes": [
                {
                    "destination": "172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall",
                    "prefix": "10.2.1.128/26"
                },
                {
                    "destination": "172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall",
                    "prefix": "10.2.4.0/24"
                },
                {
                    "destination": "ipv4 unicastaaaaaa",
                    "prefix": "address-family"
                },
                {
                    "destination": "ipv4 unicastbbbbbb",
                    "prefix": "address-family"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

And here are my Problems :

1. the last second entries from global routes are incorecct, i dont need this entries, because its wrong.
2. i need only the destination and prefix value without the description.

For the description problem i try it with replaceall. It is possible to work with regex an replaceall ? {{ prefix }} {{ destination | ORPHRASE | replaceall('', 'description', 'bla') }}

Has anyone ideas to solve my problems ? To check my parser i use this side: https://textfsm.nornir.tech/

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to use [regex patterns](https://ttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Match%20Variables/Patterns.html#) to produce more specific regex math e.g. `PREFIX` and `PREFIXV6` are regexes to match IPv4 and IPv6 prefixes respectively.

Here is modified template that adds AFI info into the results to account for both v4 and v6 routes:

```
<group name="static_routes">
router static {{ _start_ }}
 <group name="global.{{ afi }}">
 address-family {{ afi }} unicast
  <group name="routes*">
  {{ prefix | PREFIX | PREFIXV6 }} {{ destination | ORPHRASE  }}
  </group>  
 </group>
 <group name="{{ vrf_name }}">  
 vrf {{ vrf_name }}
  <group name="{{ afi }}">
  address-family {{ afi }} unicast
   <group name="routes*">
   {{ prefix | PREFIX | PREFIXV6 }} {{ destination | ORPHRASE }}
   </group> 
  </group>
 </group>
</group>
```

also added `routes*` (notice `*` at the end) to make sure routes portion of results is always a list

Tried above template on this data using https://textfsm.nornir.tech/

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ios-xr#show running-config router static                      
router static
 maximum path ipv4 10000
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  10.2.1.128/26 172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall
  10.2.4.0/24 172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall
 address-family ipv6 unicast
  ::/0 2001::7
 vrf admeg
  address-family ipv4 unicast
   10.1.192.0/24 172.28.49.140 description customerA
   10.1.194.128/26 172.28.49.140 description customerB
   10.1.195.0/25 172.28.49.140 description something
 vrf aegeg
  address-family ipv4 unicast
   10.0.0.0/8 10.49.17.134
   10.175.154.236/32 10.49.17.134
  address-family ipv6 unicast
   ::/0 2001::3
```

Got these results:

```
[
    {
        "static_routes": {
            "admeg": {
                "ipv4": {
                    "routes": [
                        {
                            "destination": "172.28.49.140 description customerA",
                            "prefix": "10.1.192.0/24"
                        },
                        {
                            "destination": "172.28.49.140 description customerB",
                            "prefix": "10.1.194.128/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "destination": "172.28.49.140 description something",
                            "prefix": "10.1.195.0/25"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aegeg": {
                "ipv4": {
                    "routes": [
                        {
                            "destination": "10.49.17.134",
                            "prefix": "10.0.0.0/8"
                        },
                        {
                            "destination": "10.49.17.134",
                            "prefix": "10.175.154.236/32"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ipv6": {
                    "routes": [
                        {
                            "destination": "2001::3",
                            "prefix": "::/0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "global": {
                "ipv4": {
                    "routes": [
                        {
                            "destination": "172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall",
                            "prefix": "10.2.1.128/26"
                        },
                        {
                            "destination": "172.24.63.44 description route_to_Firewall",
                            "prefix": "10.2.4.0/24"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ipv6": {
                    "routes": [
                        {
                            "destination": "2001::7",
                            "prefix": "::/0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Hope that helps.